# ant - How can I get the content of a variable that's name is the content of another property?

Tags: ant

I have a properties file with some variables and values:

```
ALL_WAR=*
CONS_WAR=cons-webapp.war
MAJ_WAR=maj-webapp.war
STATS_WAR=stats-webapp.war
```

I would like to get the content of one of those variables by reading a parameter of my script. I mean:

I would launch my script with the command:

```
ant -f install.xml -Dservice=ALL
```

and my script would be something like:

install.xml

```
...

<property name="war.file" value="${service}_WAR"/>

...
<copy todir="/tmp/auri">
     <fileset dir="${DELIVER_WEBAPP_DIR}" includes="${${war.file}}"/>
</copy>
```

The ${${war.file}} claims to get the content of one of the variables defined in the properties file. I don't know if that is not possible or how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

see [Ant FAQ double expanding properties](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#propertyvalue-as-name-for-property), a solution with Ant addon [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) :

starting with -Dservice=ALL

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
<!-- activate flaka property handler -->
<fl:install-property-handler/>

<property name="ALL_WAR" value="all-webapp.war"/>
<property name="war.file" value="${service}_WAR"/>

<echo>#{property[property['war.file']]}</echo>
</project>
```

will output => all-webapp.war
Note the syntax `property['...']` instead of `${...}` because of the dots in `${war.file}`,
originating from EL Syntax, 
see http://code.google.com/p/flaka/issues/detail?id=17 for more details.

this means if using the propertyname warfile instead of war.file you could write :

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
<!-- activate flaka property handler -->
<fl:install-property-handler/>

<property name="ALL_WAR" value="all-webapp.war"/>
<property name="warfile" value="${service}_WAR"/>

<echo>#{${warfile}}</echo>
</project>
```